# MVC sort list before showing it in view by name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, sorting, model

I am trying to sort my list in alphabetical order before viewing all the details on my page.

This is my code to get a clearer image of what I'm trying to say:

```
<div id= "teamMain" style="margin-left: 45px";>
  <% foreach (var item in Model.getTeams) { %>
    <a href="Statistics?id=<%: encrypted %>" class="teamImage">
        <img src="../../<%: item.image %>" alt="<%: item.name %>" />
    </a>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

I need to sort my list in alphabetical order before showing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your model you can use `OrderBy`.

For instance:

```
public IEnumerable<Teams> getTeams 
{ 
   get { return _teams.OrderBy(t => t.Name); } 
}
```

Comment: only have an option to orderByDescending

Comment: @MarkFenech - try `OrderBy`

Comment: Is there a way to sort in view engine?